# Stationary points and monotonicity

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a polynomial function, and $\mathcal{S}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For some $c\in \mathbb{R}$, assume $f(p)\geqslant c$ for all $p$ in the boundary of $\mathcal{S}$. Assume $f$ has no stationary points in $\mathcal{S}$. I want to show if this holds: $f(q)\geqslant c$ for all $q$ in the interior of $\mathcal{S}$.

If $n=1$, intuitively I can see the statement holds, but it’s not that intuitive to me if $n>1$. I understand that the fact that $f$ has no stationary points in $\mathcal{S}$ doesn’t say anything regarding its monotonicity. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To prove this, we need to consider two cases.

Case 1: All points on the boundary are equal.
From here the derivative $f'(p)$ is $0$ on the boundary, meaning that as there are no inflection points, $f(p)$ is a constant function on $\mathcal{S}$. Thus $f(p) \geq c$

Case 2: As S is a compact set, for each point in $\mathcal{S}, \exists \left \{ p_{k} \right \}, \lim_{k \to \infty} = p$, . We can define the sequence starting with two points on the boundary. Since f is greater or equal to c on the boundary, and we have considered the case where $f'(p) = 0$. $f'(p)$ must be greater than $0$ as if it was less than $0$ there would be a point on the boundary such that $f(p) < c$.

From here, we can use the continuity of $f$ and a sequence $\left \{ \mathcal{N}_{\frac{1}{n_{k}}}(q) \right \}$ of epsilon balls. Due to $f$ being continious, $f(\mathcal{N}_{\delta}(p)) \subseteq \mathcal{N}_{\epsilon}(f(p))$. So sufficiently close to the boundary point, $f(p) \geq c$. As $f'(p) > 0$, $f$ must increse on the sequence of epsilon balls, thus being greater than $c$ at the point $q$.